# twisted critical error for scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I've recently tried to learn how to use scrapy and so I am using scrapy 1.1.0rc3 on Python 3.5. I am doing a simple tutorial online, but I keep getting this error msg:

```
from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
builtins.ImportError: cannot import name '_win32stdio'
[twisted] CRITICAL:
```

People are saying that it's the Python version 3.5 that doesn't work properly and if that is the issue, should I install Python 2.7. Is it possible to have two different python versions on the same computer?

thanks!

Comment: it is absolutely possible to install multiple versions, if you have already done programming in python3 I'd recommend going with version 3.4

Comment: I have already written some code in python3 but after reading more comments it feels as though the twisted package hasnt been ported correctly to python3. Unless you think that twisted or scrapy is okay with python3.4?

Comment: I have no idea, if you have enough hard drive space why limit yourself to only one? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I might be mistaken, but I think Scrapy works best on Python 2.7. You also need pywin32. This solves a twisted error. See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html